# Flurry - custom events

Tags: swift, flurry

Hi I am wondering why the custom events I have set up don't seem to be showing on flurry.com portal.

I am going to guess it has something to do with how I have set it up - but according to the flurry documentation I have done it correctly.

This is the result when I click a button that fires logEvent

```
msg = <FlurryStreamEvent: 0x28350e000, type = 134, json = {   "fl.event.type" : "CUSTOM_EVENT",   "fl.event.id" : 2,   "fl.timed.event.duration" : 0,   "fl.event.timed" : false,   "fl.event.uptime" : 2284321185,   "fl.timed.event.starting" : false,   "fl.event.user.parameters" : {     "RXBpc29kZV90aXRsZQ==" : "WW91ciBTbyBTdHVwaWQ=",     "cG9kY2FzdA==" : "Mm5lcmRzIEluIEEgUm9vbQ=="   },   "fl.event.name" : "UG9kY2FzdF9QbGF5",   "fl.frame.version" : 1,   "fl.event.flurry.parameters" : {    },   "fl.event.timestamp" : 1603026151045 }>
```

My concern is `"fl.event.flurry.parameters" : {    },` it's empty - I have no idea if it is meant to be empty..

This is how I am calling it:

```
 let data = ["podcast": post.title, "Episode_title":podcast.title]
                                Flurry.logEvent("Podcast_Play", withParameters: data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fl.event.user.parameters is the one that contains the parameters you set, so in your example, they are reporting in. Not seeing them in the portal could be due to the expected time it takes for data to propagate. If it takes more than several hours, email us at support@flurry.com with the details.

Comment: Can I just say that your analytics system rocks!